# I am using tkinter in python 3.9

Tags: python

The code..

```
if mvar & evar == "root":
```

gives this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: What did you expect `mvar & evar` to do? Do you mean `if mvar == evar == 'root'` ?

Answer (score 0):

try saying:

```py
if mvar.get() & evar.get() == "root":
```

when you use intvar stringvar or whatever you will have to type .get() or else it will return something with PY_VAR0

Answer (score 0):

Ok so heres the case, you are just saying mvar, which returns the type of var youused. Fx if you say mvar = stringvar()
Then it will return the id of it.
To get the string out of it youwill have to say
“ mvar.get() == evar.get() “

Answer (score -1):

I think you would like to use 'and' operator instead of '&'.
AND is a logical operator.
& is a bitwise 'AND' operator

```
if mvar == "root" and evar == "root":
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. It is equivalent to `if (mvar) and (evar == "root")`